# How to mv file without race conditions?

Tags: python, locking

I am encountering a race condition in renaming the files by my application written in **python**.
Exact problem below:

A csh script will be dispatched by the application to the grid, where it will run and try to rename a file `A.run` to `A.com`.

Meanwhile, when this job is killed through the application (one of the features is to kill the job submitted), the application tries to rename `A.run` to `A.kil`.

However, I am encountering race condition when the files are being renamed, if both the operations are happening at the same time. I am trying to understand if any lock can be set by the `csh` script on the file, so that during that time, the kill function is not called at all.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: What does the kill function actually do? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: The kill function issues the kill command for the grid (bkill/qdel depending on teh grid selected) and then it will  rename the file from A.run to A.kil

Comment: Assuming you're sending a sensible signal, then just block the signal when you don't want to be killed.

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'sending a sensible signal'?? Thanks

Comment: I mean not one that can be blocked, like SIGHUP or SIGINT. Not one that cannot, like SIGKILL.

Answer (score 0):

The [flock](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) command (available as a shell command and a python function) may help you avoid the race condition.